# Drude model for diodes

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering

Well I was wondering how we can apply the drude model for diodes.The normal drude model is used on conductors and insulators and since the diode in forward bias is a good conductor(not the best but no the worst)how can we apply the drude model.What I am confused is that the drude model is only for lattices that contain cations and neutral atoms and I find this issue:
When an electron starts approaching a negatively charged boron ion it cant collide with it so it losses all of its kinetic energy . If that electron could pass near the boron anion it would repel other electrons and cause electron trafficking . What am I missing?

Comment: First, I'm not sure just why one would want to bother with a Drude model for a diode, but... Second, one thing you are missing is that there aren't many dopants (one in a million atoms or so), and they just act as another scattering center that will change the $\tau$ in the Drude model just a bit.

Comment: The cant act as scattering due to : boron anions and electrons.Both negatively charged repel each other.

Comment: Of course they exhibit scattering. Any forces, positive or negative, cause scattering.

Comment: They cant collide with each other.

Comment: There is still a force. In Rutherford scattering the two particles don't 'collide' with each other either. Or comets in hyperbolic orbits around the sun...

Comment: How do you imagine the "collision" between electron and positive ions?

Comment: Fun fact to consider - the Rutherford scattering formula holds for all $1/r$ potentials, either attractive (gravity, Coulomb with dislike charges) or repulsive (Coulomb with like charges). The exact path taken by the scattering particle is slightly different, but the differential cross sections are the same.